Blonde heroine in a lush place ties hair with glove and wears sari
Forgive me, I will be as detailed as I possibly can about this, but what I know of the movie is quite fuzzy in my mind.
I remember a woman, with blonde hair living in what doesn't look like America, I'm not entirely sure where the movie is filmed though, Very green.
Anyway, she has a suitcase or some sort of thing full with children's sandals, and uses them to confuse a man with a truck. Ahe wears them to I think steal from him and have him believe children are taking his things. 
At one point in the movie she's washing dishes with those yellow rubber gloves and her hair keeps getting in her face so she decided to tie it up. She does so with one of the gloves I believe and then everything starts getting stuck in/to her hair. Appliances and what not. 
Another part: She's with a bunch of Indian women in a Sari and one of the women keeps saying "Your sari, your sari!" and the main woman is like "I am sorry" or something and runs away her gown trailing behind her on the hillside. I think it's a red gown.
Anyway, That's all I really remember, and It's been killing me to figure out what it is. I've Googled a million and one things trying to figure it out. I just can't.

I'm not entirely sure what to change the title to. I'm very new at this! I think the whole thing is full of odd details ahaha.

While I agree that extra details are always helpful, this is actually a relatively detailed ID question (from my experience, anyway), at least when it comes to specfic scenes.

This is The Price of Milk from 2000, a somewhat surreal movie about a farmer and his fiancee living in the lush hills of New Zealand. The suitcase full of children's shoes, the scene where she ties her hair with a glove when washing dishes and gets some pots stuck to it, her in a red sari replying "I am, I am" to "Your sari, your sari", it's all there.

Here's the trailer; the movie is also currently available on Youtube in 11 parts (here's part 1). Gotta love the opening credits which are gradually revealed on a quilt!
